# group-by/apply with Pandas and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to do a groupby and apply operation on a pandas dataframe using multiprocessing (in the hope of speeding up my code). For example, if I have a dataframe like the following:

```
            A  B  C
cluster_id         
1           1  2  3
1           1  2  3
2           4  5  6
2           7  8  9
```

I would like to apply a function on the columns and group them by the cluster_id. In a simple case where the function is just the sum

```
def my_func(x):
    return sum(x)
```

then the operation should yield:

```
            A   B   C
cluster_id         
1           2   4   6
2           11  13  15
```

There are some similar posts on SO, i did manage to get somewhere close but havent really solved it. My code fails and I dont know how to fix it. This is what I have come up with

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def _apply_df(args):
    df, func = args
    return df.groupby(level=0).apply(func)


def mp_apply(df, func):
    workers = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=workers)
    split_dfs = np.array_split(df, workers, axis=1)
    result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func) for d in split_dfs])
    pool.close()
    result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return pd.concat([i[1] for i in result])


def my_func(x):
    return sum(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 2], [7, 8, 9, 2]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'cluster_id'])
    df = df.set_index('cluster_id')
    out = mp_apply(df, my_func)
    print(out)
```

I am getting the error:

```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

and It looks like it fails on the line

```
result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func) for d in split_dfs])
```

The parameter `d` that is passed into `_apply_df` looks to be empty.

Any help/ideas highly appreciated. I am using Python 3.6 if that matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main causes of issues in your code

1. The use of the python's built-in sum function. this is a function that takes an iterable of number and return their sum. 
   e.g. if you try to sum a slice of the dataframe df, you will get the same error traceback

> sum(df.loc[1])
>
> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-60-6dea0ab0880f> in <module>()
>     ----> 1 sum(df.loc[1])
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
> ```

To fix this, you'll need to use pandas `sum` function as shown below

```
df.loc[1].sum()

#output 
A    2
B    4
C    6
dtype: int64
```

As you can see, this will produce the expected result. i.e. sums the columns in the data-slice

2. The second issue is the "reduce" stage. each process will return a single dataframe, the lines

   result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])

   return pd.concat([i[1] for i in result])

The first line will produce an error as whenever none of the result has a column called 0. similar issue with the second line.  this can be resolved as follows

```
return pd.concat(result,axis=1)
```

Now the code will run without issue given the data being used.

The overall code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def _apply_df(args):
    df, func = args
    return df.groupby(level=0).apply(func)


def mp_apply(df, func):
    workers = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=workers)
    split_dfs = np.array_split(df, workers, axis=1)
    result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func) for d in split_dfs])
    pool.close()
    #result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return pd.concat(result,axis=1)


def my_func(x):
    return x.sum()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 2], [7, 8, 9, 2]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'cluster_id'])
    df = df.set_index('cluster_id')
    out = mp_apply(df, my_func)
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
             A   B   C
cluster_id            
1            2   4   6
2           11  13  15
```

Comment: Great stuff! Very helpful comments. Many thanks for helping out, this clarifies quite a few points. Sadly for me, multiprocessing doesnt get things any faster, it now runs a lot slower for some reason. Maybe it is pickling that gets in the way, I dont know.

Comment: You're welcome. keep in mind that pandas is designed with performance in mind. i.e. it's already highly optimised and takes advantage of parallelism. the trick is to use it efficiently. try `out = df.groupby(level=0).sum()`.

Comment: how do you make sure that `np.array_split(df, workers, axis=1)` will not split rows belong to the same group into different chunks?

Comment: pd.concat(result,axis=1)    :   performance gets lower when the group by are more then 1million